# Count how many times quantity exceeds over limit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How I can count with iteration for my product quantity if it exceeds more than can fit in one pallet.

Example one pallet limit is 100 and if that product quantity exceeds 101 then it adds 2 iteration like second pallet.

My code:

```
$tkp = 1;
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    if (!empty(get_post_meta($cart_item['variation_id'], '_number_field', true))) { //this checks if pallet price is empty or not.
        $a = $cart_item['quantity']; // these are products with pallets already.
    } else {
        $atk = strstr(get_post_meta($cart_item['variation_id'], '_alus_al', true), "units", true); // it checks how many products can be in pallet for this variation (ex. 100 units)

        if ($cart_item['quantity'] > $atk) {
            $tk = $tkp++;
        }
        $tkc = $tk * 8; // 8 is pallet price.
    }

    $calc = $a * 8 + $tkc;
    WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Alused', 'txtdomain'), $calc);
}
```

Comment: `ceil( $quantity / 100 )`

Answer (score 0):

You should do `$tk = ceil($cart_item['quantity'] / $atk)` and don't do the if check.
So you calculate how many palettes you need. The ceil function rounds those up, because you can't send a half palette

Comment: I have 3 products, first product quantity 1, second product quantity 101, third product quantity 201 and it shows 3 and it shows $tk value is 2.